# Char string to hex char array in C++

Tags: c++, hex

I have a CLinux device, that i need to transform some data.
The input is something like

```
char mytest[] = "020441010C0000003131203131203131313103";
```

and i need to have

```
mytest2[] = {0x02,0x04,0x41,0x01,0x0C,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x31,0x31,0x20,0x31,0x31,0x20,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x03}
```

This is the code that i've tried, but it doesn't compile cause the sstream is not on the device OS..
Can some give me another solution to transform the data?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
std::string myStr = "1122AA010A";

std::stringstream ss;
int n;
for(int i = 0; i<myStr.length(); ) {
    std::istringstream(myStr.substr(i,2))>>std::hex>>n;
    ss<<(char)n;
    i += 2;
    }

std::string result = ss.str();

std::cout<<"\n"<<result<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing hex is pretty easy. Convert each digit to its hex value, and combine them together into a single char.

```
int FromHexDigit(char c) //Returns a number from 0 to 15
{
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c-'0';
    else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        return c-'A' + 10;
    else if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        return c-'a' + 10;
    else
        return -1; //Not a hex digit :(
}
```

Then the main loop becomes:

```
std::string result;
for(int i = 0; i<myStr.length(); i += 2) {
    char d1 = myStr[i], d2 = myStr[i+1]; //Those are the two consecutive hex digits
    int n = FromHexDigit(d1)*16 + FromHexDigit(d2); //Convert to a number
    result += (char)n; //Put into the result string
}
```

Note the i+=2 portion in the for loop header. We're processing the string in two byte chunks. There's no handling of the situation that the string has an odd number of characters.

Comment: What do you mean with `convert each digit to its hex value` ? There's no way to work like with substrings, working with 2 digits at at time? ( cause they're already in hex )

Comment: @SE-LM you can do a substring of size 2 then make a sstring with it then extract in hexa, but this is much more expensive

Comment: is strange to put the result in a string, a `vector<unsigned>` or equivalent seems more natural no ?